# Deploy multiple applications to a single EC2 instance using AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am have deployed a .Net website to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.  I want to now deploy another .Net web project (a web service) to the same EC2 instance that was created by AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but the selection to "use and existing environment" in the Environment page of the publishing wizard is greyed out.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Asked this quite a few years back now. Have since moved on to use Azure Web Sites, which give me the flexibility and ease of use I wanted when I asked this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update: This is now possible https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/08/aws-elastic-beanstalk-supports-asp-net-core-and-multi-app-net-support/

No. .Net deployment has some limitations on EB compared to the other frameworks. You cannot deploy multiple applications on the same instance.

Comment: Can we do the above in php??

Comment: Deploying more than one application to AWS using Elastic Beanstalk [is now possible](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/Tx29MH65I0HLAN5/Multiple-Application-Support-for-NET-and-Elastic-Beanstalk)

Comment: @vini did you ever get an answer to your question about using php? I am curious about this too.

Comment: Php is Linux so why not use docker compose file to load multiple php dockers

Comment: I think you can deploy it as of 2023

Answer (score 3):

You can use Multicontainer docker environment to deploy multiple applications http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a multiple-app deployment using the Visual Studio AWS Toolkit:

[docs.aws.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/deployment-beanstalk-multiple-application.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it for Tomcat environments - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-multiple-war-files.html.

> To create an application source bundle that contains multiple WAR files, organize the WAR files using the following structure.

```
MyApplication.zip
├── .ebextensions
├── .platform
├── foo.war
├── bar.war
└── ROOT.war
```

> When you deploy a source bundle containing multiple WAR files to an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment, each application is accessible from a different path off of the root domain name. The preceding example includes three applications: foo, bar, and ROOT. ROOT.war is a special file name that tells Elastic Beanstalk to run that application at the root domain, so that the three applications are available at http://MyApplication.elasticbeanstalk.com/foo, http://MyApplication.elasticbeanstalk.com/bar, and http://MyApplication.elasticbeanstalk.com.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot deploy a "Web Site" and a "Web Application" on the same instance (or set of instances, such as that formed by ElasticBeastalk) because they run different resources and policies. This is accordingly to the tutorial i came across on their site.

Comment: Not true. You have docker and multi. Net apps and there's even a workaround for multiple java war files.