# Cost-Effective way to Deploy 2 .NET Apps on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I see this question:
[Deploy multiple applications to a single EC2 instance using AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973956/deploy-multiple-applications-to-a-single-ec2-instance-using-aws-elastic-beanstal)

So my next question is: what is the most cost-effective way to handle this situation?

I have two closely-related, but distinct, MVC-based webapps I need to deploy.  I'm trying to find the most efficient way of deploying them, without too much waste.
I'm thinking:

1. Combine them into a single web deploy package and let beanstalk deploy that?
2. Reuse certain elements of beanstalk, such as the load balancer?  All I'd really need is another EC2 instance (assuming I still can't deploy multiple apps to a single IIS), and share the scaling group, load balancer, etc...

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to create custom AMI based on AWS Beanstalk AMI for .NET application and than use it for deployment.

Comment: I started to get the feeling that may be the answer - so I would then setup my own deployment process, rather than use beanstalk's? eg. my own ftp or rsync or something, and my own script to copy to IIS, for example?

Comment: May be it's make sense. However, I would recommend instead of ftp, rsync etc to have a look to Web Deploy 3.0 (http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy).

Comment: Can I ask you question, why you don't want to deploy your application to Windows Azure? It's more native environment for .NET applications than AWS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - webdeploy: that's all well and good, I'm open to using the webdeploy package/zip, as long as I can script it into msbuild or something and deploy with the CLI, but that still doesn't give me a real starting point to customizing the AMI - I copied the EB AMI but am not seeing any deploy scripts on it.. (just a hostmanager exe)?

Comment: I'd be open to considering Azure, but it's nice to invest in learning one platform that can do both linux/java apps, as well as .net.  Azure also seems to require that your apps have specialized components compiled-in ("Roles"), and I'm not sure if Azure has the maturity (e.g. VPC's, private subnets, etc...) that I know Amazon has (maybe it does).

Comment: Azure is more PaaS than IaaS, and also in the end of last year were introduced a lot of new services like: virtual machines, web sites etc.

Comment: Thanks Vadim - I got something to work as a POC (2 apps running on same ec2 under BS by setting up a custom ami) - I think this will work out.  One app will be deployed via BS, the other will be pushed out manually by my own process (thinking maybe rsync'ing the webdeploy archive, then writing something that will autodeploy them).  I'll also try to check out Azure when I have time :)