# Can I have multiple websites in one AWS Elastic Beanstalk Application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm very confused about Elastic Beanstalk Application

I currently host all my websites in a windows server iis based, elastic ip server.

it is a medium ec2 instance so I pay quite a bit.

I was considering migrating it to Elastic Beanstalk Application instead of using my current one.

after creating one Elastic Beanstalk Application I notice it creates a t1.micro ec2 instance and Amazon say they scale under demand, which is fine.

my question is about how many Elastic Beanstalk Application applications I need to have?

can I have all my 30 websites under 1 Elastic Beanstalk Application?

if I have to create an Elastic Beanstalk Application(which is a t1.micro) for each website I will spend over $400.00 month

please, clarify

thanks

Answer (score 3):

With IIS, the option of deploying multiple apps is not available.
Please refer to the following stackoverflow discussion
[Deploy multiple applications to a single EC2 instance using AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973956/deploy-multiple-applications-to-a-single-ec2-instance-using-aws-elastic-beanstal)

This feature is only available for java applications.
You can bundle multple WAR files into one ZIP file for deployment.

Here is aws documentation for the feature release.
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/06/aws-elastic-beanstalk-supports-multiple-war-files-and-m4-instances/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use following steps to reduce your bill

**Option 1:**

1. Create static S3 webhosting for your website
2. Expose via Lambdaage and cloud front your application .

**Option 2:**

1. Create multi container docker images and use docker compose
2. deploy on EBS or ECS and ngnix reverse proxy configure different host port