# Does AWS Beanstalk hosting charge for every EC2 instance it creates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to AWS ElasticBeanstalk. As i have started working on AWS ElasticBeanstalk i have some confusion which are as follows.

1.Does Amazon charge for every EC2 instance which is created to run ElasticBeanstalk app under free tier.

2.Is it possible to host multiple app under samne EC2 instance which is created for Elasticbeanstalk i.e ASp.net ,Web Api and angular 4 app under same elasticbeanstalk.

Please help me to clear my issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. If the EC2 instances used for Elastic Beanstalk fall under the free tier (i.e. within the first 12 months of account ownership, they're small enough instances, use less than 750 hours/month, etc.), then they'll be free. It doesn't matter if the instances are used for an Elastic Beanstalk application or something else.
2. Yes, it is possible to host multiple Elastic Beanstalk applications on the same EC2 instance. See [this related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973956/deploy-multiple-applications-to-a-single-ec2-instance-using-aws-elastic-beanstal).

Comment: It's worth noting that as far as the free tiers are concerned, you will not be charged for usage *until* you hit the [free tier limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/free-tier-limits.html) for the instace type.

Comment: It's dependent on the total number of hours instances have been running during a month (must be <= 750 hours per month). That could be 2 instances running for 375 hours each, or 750 instances running 1 hour each, etc.