# How to deploy Nodejs in an existing instance (EC2) in AWS which already have php environment?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cicd, aws-devops

As you understand from the title, that I have to  deploy an nodejs application build on Nextjs on the existing instance.
The situation is:

1. can we deploy nodejs with the instance that already have php environment? (I think it is possible as we normally work on our local computer on daily basis).
2. how to create a basic pipeline for that? (I go through some tutorials on the Elastic Beanstalk in AWS, but it creates a new instance for that which I don't want, is there is any alternative ways to do that.)
3. how to connect pipeline with instance and also with the project folder.

Also, I've heard some rumors that, when the pipeline builds our projects, then it will delete all the existing projects in the instance. (is it really true).

I only have the book knowledge, but never done a practical on that.

Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: This will help - [Deploying multiple services on a single instance of AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://medium.com/finnovate-io/deployment-multiple-services-on-a-single-instance-of-aws-elastic-beanstalk-f9bc00908c64). Also, you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10973956/8244632) of StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for response. it helps me a lot. By this i am able to reaserch more and  properly understanding the   use cases of  Elastick Beanstalk.