# Can I deploy 2 environments (2 different spring boot applications) on a single EC2 instance using Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a spring boot application which is deployed using Elastic Beanstalk which manages an EC2 instance. Now I want to deploy another Spring Boot application. Can I deploy it in the same EC2 instance? I want to do this to save cost of another EC2. Couldn't find much of help over internet. Please let me know if this can be achieved.

Comment: yes, you can the only limiting factor is that they have to run on different ports. If you want to call them both directly on port 80 or 443 you should use sth like nginx to configure which url pattern gets mapped to which instance

Comment: I can run on different ports. How to configure the same EC2 for both the apps? please give some details.

Comment: @JAsgarov how would you configure Elastic Beanstalk to manage the deployment of two separate applications? This isn't just an EC2 question, this is an Elastic Beanstalk question.

Comment: @ShrikarKalagi Have you looked at the answers to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973956/deploy-multiple-applications-to-a-single-ec2-instance-using-aws-elastic-beanstal